# Uipath automation

Tags: automation, uipath, rpa

I want to take the report of last one download details from the mysql database and sent to my project manager on every monday through the email so the process remains same only date would be change dynamically so, I would like to automate this process using RPA UIpath.

Anyone could you help me to achieve this process.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use 'Database' package to connect to sql db and and run the query.
Schedule the program to run every Monday using Orchestrator. 
Create the report with current date using DateTime function

Comment: Some working examples here would go a long way to helping anyone understand what you're saying

Answer (score 4):

There will be some extra steps like transforming data as necessary etc, but the basic outline of this process is as follows

1. Download MySQL ODBC Drivers [MySQL site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html)
2. Control Panel -> Setup ODBC Data Sources (32-bit) setup User or System DSN, make sure to test your connection to see if it works OK (it's similar to how you set it up in MySQL Workbench [or read about it here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/amsw))
3. In your UiPath Studio Package Manager, add [Database Activities Pack](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/about-the-database-activities-pack).
4. Get your data using `UiPath.Database.Activities.ExecuteQuery` [activity](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/execute-query) to a `DataTable`
5. Write your data to an Excel file using `Write Range` [activity](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/write-range)
6. Send your mail through SMTP using `UiPath.Mail.SMTP.Activities.SendMail` including freshly created Excel file as attachment

Answer (score 2):

First step Take the data using database activity

Create an automation in UiPath to attach and send to your respective email

Schedule it own orchestrator.

Though not exactly but atleast sending a mail by taking credential from Orchestrator is shown in this article

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-sequence-project-for-sending-a-mail-using-smtp-activity-by-taking-crede/